# Lambda API Gateway POST params

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I'm trying to access as key value from this simple Lambda

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "net/http"
)


func Draw(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
        Body:       "Draw API " + request.Body,
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    // https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serverless-api-with-go-and-aws-lambda

    lambda.Start(Draw)
}
```

And with a simple curl

```
curl -d "timestamp=11223344" https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/draw
```

I get

```
Draw API timestamp=11223344
```

How can i get a Key / Value string or map with param name and value? Unfortunately i cannot use json as input

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [`net/url.ParseQuery`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseQuery)

```
import "net/url"

...

kv, err := url.ParseQuery("foo=bar")
```